# eXist-db HTML output 'stalling' after a few lines

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In eXist-DB 4.4 I'm facing a problem I don't know how to continue diagnosing after exhausting a variety of debugging options for several hours. Source files in the edit at bottom.

I know it's a longshot, but I'm hoping someone might have come across this issue before in eXist-DB. Or at least know of other tools for tracing this in detail - I use eXide for writing XQuery, etc in eXist-DB.

The eXist `app` environment I've set up is quite simple, and every page follows the same mechanism. Until now, every page has output fine.

But I've been wrestling for a few hours to understand why I'm getting an output to the browser (under Chrome, Firefox and Safari) literally cutting out mid-element exactly like below **but only from one HTML template**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta conten
```

Every page uses the same template system through an HTML page, the problem in this case is `place.html`. I've reduced it to nothing except a `div` and a call to a `templates:surround`:

```
<div data-template="templates:surround" 
        data-template-with="templates/site_wrapper.html" 
        data-template-at="content">

    <div><p>Finally, an output!</p></div>

</div>
```

The above calls a `templates:surround` = `site_wrapper.html` which is used by every other page on the site without fail or error. This template `site_wrapper.html` receives no parameters although it calls to other templates in the form of XQuery functions (again, no parameters).

When I look in the eXist dashboard monitoring tools, I see the `view` barely registers any processing time (compared to other pages).

As for possible sources of problems:

- the `controller.xql`...no, because a partial page **is** being spit out?
- the view...no, because I haven't touched a thing in there beyond what has been working for weeks?
- the template `site_wrapper.html`....no, it's the same as used by every other page and therefore should not pose problems?

I'm flummoxed.

EDIT:

XAR file is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj2vqo1bkarci46/deheresi-2018-11-06.xar?dl=0 Global system variable configured in `globalvar.xql`

One can compare `place.html` (which doesn't work) with `person.html` (which does work) as they have identical structures. This can be seen in action by opening `exist/apps/deheresi/doc/MS609-0001` and clicking on links in the text. Any link containing `/deheresi/place/foo_person_name` brings the above result.

Comment: Notwithstanding other possible solutions...I rebuilt the entire `place.html` structure under a different name, tested fine, then went through everything to rename it to `place`, and now everything works fine. I used a text comparison editor to check the differences and there was no problem. It's likely some corruption somewhere. I'll leave this question up for future searchers....

Comment: i can imagine two kinds of corruptions that might be to blame. 1) the more likely: an illegal invisible character slipped into the document probably when when copy pasting from the web 2) an actual database corruption. While unlikely you should perform a backup and see if the integrated integrity check reports any problems